# How can I calculate the average between two text files based on matrixes?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix, text, mean

I am fairly new to using MATLAB. I have two text files that have 500 rows x 100 columns and every one of it has a random value.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 2
4 5 6 6 8
```

So my question is, corresponding to the row and column, how can I calculate the average of each particular field corresponding to the row and column?

For instance, at (1,1) in text1.txt is 20 and at (1,1) in text2.txt is 40. The average is 30 and I want to display this result in an another file at (1,1).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the files are named 'a' and 'b':

```
load a
load b
c=(a+b)/2;
save('c','c','-ascii');
```